# Position a background using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I'm using Bootstrap (3 or 4), and would like to have a diagonal line that runs across the full width of the page, with a middle that stays more or less in the center of a fixed-width content area (sometimes text, sometimes image), even as the browser window is resized. I have an image of how I imagine this to look when done:

[An image of what this looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6LYz.png)

I've been using a triangle-shaped white SVG to make the angle, but I'm having trouble keeping it in frame. The angle of the line should remain the same no matter what the window size is.

Comment: You can use contain or cover modes of background-size on a 100% width and height div, or on the body. Did you try those?

Comment: Good ideas. I added some info to the original post, but I would like the angle of the line to remain constant no matter what the size of the window is. Also, because this is responsive, I don't know the size of the content or exactly where it is positioned.

Comment: Okay, what I have understood is the angle in svg dynamically changes when you resize it. So you should create a static image, or create your background image using gradients.

Comment: @st. That's interesting. I tried a gradient (background: linear-gradient(-7deg,  #2989d8 0%,#2989d8 50%,#ffffff 50.1%,#ffffff 100%); and it doesn't distort, but it isn't a smooth line either which is why I was using the SVG. I could possible use a .png, but I worry that to preserve appearance the file will have to be 8000px wide to hold up on a large retina screen.

Comment: Well you have a third option, which is a little hacky but, you can fix your svg width to 8000px and height what it should be. And use it like its a png file. That way you can save some bandwidth and memory. I can't think of any other option really :)

Comment: @st. I get the theory, but am struggling with the practice—may I ask for your help with a code snippet?

Comment: I'm not near my pc right now so I can help you in 10 hours from now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go.

I made a svg file to you, feel free to change it size or colors.

```
<svg id="backgroundImage" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280 720" style="position: fixed; top:0px; left:0px">
  <polygon points="0,0 0,500 1280,350 1280,0" style="fill:#2989d8;stroke:transparent;stroke-width:0" />
</svg>
```

What I did is, defined a viewBox first, as our svg boundaries. Then set svg's width to 100%. Also styled position as fixed, set top and left to 0 px.

Then I draw a polygon, which is actually not angle based, its a fixed sized polygon. So when its containers size changes, it just scales accordingly.

You can see it's working on the link below.

http://codepen.io/st-/full/wMPayV/